# Shopping cart with hover dropdown

Tags: javascript, html

I'm uses a previous design of shopping cart, but can't applied the option hover shoppign cart, this its a code example.

My code

```
$('#cart').hover(function(e) {       
    $(".shopping-cart").stop(true, true).addClass("active");
  }, function() {
    $(".shopping-cart").stop(true, true).removeClass("active");
  });
```

I need the contents of the cart not to disappear until the mouse pointer is out.

**Example codepen**

See the Pen [Shopping Cart Dropdown](https://codepen.io/alexd2/pen/PRbjxz/) by Eduardo ([@alexd2](https://codepen.io/alexd2)) on [CodePen](https://codepen.io).

Comment: I feel like you could probably accomplish something similar with just css

Comment: How is the example with css?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use [Multiple Selector](https://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/) will solve your issue.

```
  $('#cart, .shopping-cart').hover(function(e) {
    $(".shopping-cart").stop(true, true).addClass("active");
  }, function() {
    $(".shopping-cart").stop(true, true).removeClass("active");
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

With pure css, you could probably do something like this.

```css
.cart {
background-color: lightblue;
  float: right;
  text-align: right;
  position: relative;
}

.list {
  
  background-color: lightgreen;
  height: 250px;
  width: 300px;
  border: 2px solid red;
right: 0;
  position: absolute;
  transition: 1s all;
  transform: scale(0) ;
  transform-origin: 100% 0%;
}

.cart:hover > .list {
  transform: scale(1);
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="cart">
    This is a cart
    <div class="list">
      some long list
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

`position: absolute` is optional (along with the accompanying css), just that if you don't have it, then the cart will be as long as the child's width, which may or may not be desirable.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove "active" from this

```
$(".shopping-cart").stop(true, true).removeClass("active");
```

to this one

```
$(".shopping-cart").stop(true, true).removeClass("");
```